# How to correct validation on perl?

Tags: perl

Even though I am sort of an expert on perl, I have no idea of Validation?
Here is my question?

```
 <form method="post" action="/~it.jasonc/cgi-bin/user.pl">
   <tr><td>Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="name"></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Address:</td><td><input type="text" name="address"></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Street:</td><td><input type="text" name="street"></td></tr>
   <tr><td>City:</td><td><input type="text" name="city"></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Town:</td><td><input type="text" name="town"></td></tr>
   <tr><td>County:</td><td><input type="text" name="county"></td></tr><br>
   <tr><td>Email:</td><td><input type="text" name="email"></td></tr><br>
   <tr><td>Holiday Season:</td><td><select name="hol">
   <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Continue"></td></tr></table></body> 
   </html>
```

My question is: Every time I go to my webpage and press continue without entering information, It says "Invalid Name, Please Enter Name", thats fine.  When i enter in a name and press continue it still says "Invalid Name, Please Enter Name"?

No other error messages comes up other than Name?  I have all the validation and error messages in a .pl file??

Here is the code I am using for the validation??

```
&trim ($name);
if (($name eq "" ) || (($name =~ tr/ //) < 1) ) {
  print "<p><font color=\"#ff0000\">Invalid Name, Please enter a valid name.</font>";
  &back;
}
else {
  print "<p><b>Order Details<b>\n";
  print "<p>Name: $name\n";
}
```

There is what i am using in my .pl file (I am only taken name for now)?

Comment: How should we know? We can't see the code you are using to perform this validation.

Comment: Please [learn to love labels](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/)  and don't use tables for [layout](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=css+forms).

Comment: I have updated my question Quentin?

Comment: `&trim`? Why are you writing Perl 4 style code? That Perl doesn't help all that much, we can't see how you are trying to get the value from the form data in the first place.

Comment: counting spaces for name validation is poor solution.

Comment: My Instructor gave me a sample validation form, and i was just going with that.. He showed us what to do, I took notes.  Now mine is not work.  I am starting to get annoyed with perl!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML is invalid. You cannot have a `<form>` element as a parent of a `<tr>` element. A form can be entirely with in a table cell or entire around an entire table. You can't wrap a form around part of a table. When trying to recover from this error, browsers often break forms.

Test your HTML with a [markup validator](http://validator.w3.org/). (Edit: Fixed link from previous copy/paste error)

Comment: The validation markup is just giving me errors because it thinks the .pl file is a .html file??

Comment: You need to validate your HTML, not your Perl.

Comment: I found out what was wrong in the end, Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

Close the `form` tag first. 
Use `label` instead of `table`  tag